# How to sketch $\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}}\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}} (x^2+y^2+z^2) dzdxdy$ region of integration on paper?

Tags: calculus

What's the best way to sketch the region of integration in cartesian coordinates of a 3D math figure such as $$\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}}\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}} (x^2+y^2+z^2) \; dz\;dx\;dy$$ on paper?

I have an idea what it should look like, $y$-axis, should have boundaries at $y=0$ and $y=3$, I know $x=\sqrt{9-y^2}$ results into a circle like shape with radius $3$, there should a cone upward from the $z$-axis ($\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$) and a cone downwards ($\sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}$), but I don't how to to actually sketch it on paper.

Comment: The figure is symmetric about the z-axis, so simply draw a triangle to represent the cone, a circular arc to represent the spherical section, and the circular boundary is a line.  Then imagine rotating this 2D figure about the z-axis to get your 3D figure.

Comment: @RonGordon Thank you for your suggestion. Could you show me a sketch of how you would do it on paper, please?

Comment: Sorry, no.  Too much work and fumbling with pen and paper.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the $\sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}$ doesn't represent a *cone*, but a spherical surface centered at the origin, with a radius of $3\sqrt2$.

So this spherical surface meets the bottom cone exactly at a distance of $3$ from the $z$-axis; all the bounds on $x$ and $y$ do is to select those points in the $xy$-plane where $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le \sqrt{18-x^2-y^2}$.

In other words, your region is a [spherical sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector), the intersection of a radius-$3\sqrt2$ sphere and a right cone with its apex at the center of the sphere.

You can look at the figures in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector) or [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalSector.html) to see how other people tend to draw such shapes.

---

This also suggests that actually evaluating the integral will be much easier if you move to spherical coordinates. It then becomes simply
$$  \iiint\limits_{(r,\theta,\phi)\in[0,3\sqrt2]\times[0,2\pi]\times[0,\pi/4]} r^2 \, dV $$
with no interdependence between the coordinates.